# Cors Policy Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I got below issue while sending auth header jwt token from angular.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:52278/api/user/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**.Net Core**

```html
            var origins = Configuration["CorsUrl"].Split(",");
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("BasePolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .WithOrigins(origins)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });

            });
```

```
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCors("BasePolicy");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

**Angular:**

```js
    signUpAdmin(data: AdminSignUpModel) {
        return this.httpClient.post('user/signup', data,this.getCommonOptions());
    }
```

```html
private _token: string = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

   protected getCommonOptions() {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this._token}`,
                
            })
        };
        return httpOptions;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have your Angular CLI development server running on http://localhost:4200 and you want to access the server running on http://localhost:52278 you need to
set up a proxy for API calls in angular.

To create Angular PROXY

1. Create a file `proxy.conf.json` at the root of our Angular CLI project.

   The content should look as follows

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:52278",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Now All requests made to `/api/...` from within our application will be forwarded to `http://localhost:52278/api/....`

2. Configure angular.json with proxyConfig key under the architect>serve>options that point to the src/proxy.conf.json as below

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
```

3. Now, simply run `ng serve` and you are done.

***Side note:** **This is NOT FOR PRODUCTION***

use it for development there are other, much more sophisticated solutions for your production environment, whether it is to deploy your app directly “into your backend app” or by serving it via Apache 2 or Nginx.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention to edit angular.json file after creating proxy.conf.json :)

Answer (score 0):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:52278/api/user/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

To troubleshoot the issue, please try to specify the allowed origins in code rather than get data from configuration settings, like below.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("BasePolicy",
    builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:44336") 
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
    });

});
```

Please note that the specified URL(s) must not contain a trailing slash (`/`), such as `http://localhost:4200/`.

And please modify code to call the `UseCors` method after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization`.

```
app.UseRouting();
//...

app.UseCors("BasePolicy");

app.UseAuthorization();
```

For more information about enabling CORS in ASP.NET Core, please check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware